# Draw a box in OpenCV with my mouse (using Mat not IplImage)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to draw a box in OpenCV in a particular place so that I can crop it there.  Right now I am trying to draw a recatnge around my region of interest but I am getting an error at drawBox() in my mouseEvent().  Below is my code and following is the error output.  How can I get this to work?  Everywhere I am looking has older IplImage and other deprecated functions.

```
#include stuff

using namespace cv;

bool isDrawing = false;
Point start, end;

void drawBox(Point start, Point end, Mat& img){
Scalar color = (0,255,0);
rectangle(img, start, end, color, 1, 8, 0);
return;
}

void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param){
if(isDrawing){
    if(evt==CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP){
        printf("up %d %d\n",x,y);
        isDrawing = false;
        end.x = x;
        end.y = y;
        drawBox(start, end, (Mat&) param);
        return;
    }
}
else{
    if(evt==CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){
        printf("down %d %d\n",x,y);
        isDrawing = true;
        start.x = x;
        start.y = y;
        return;
    }
}
}

int main(){

Mat feed = imread("C:/Users/Timo/Desktop/image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

namedWindow("Feed");
imshow("Feed", feed);

cvSetMouseCallback("Feed", mouseEvent, &feed);

waitKey(0);

return 1;
}
```

CONSOLE

```
down 293 26
up 520 217
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed <cn <= 4> in unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 845
```

POPUP

```
Unhandled exception at 0x80000000 in opencv_project.exe: )xC0000005: Access violation.
```

OUTPUT LOG

```
First-chance exception at 0x7796c41f in opencv_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002de9b4..
Unhandled exception at 0x7796c41f in opencv_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002de9b4..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a pointer to `cvSetMouseCallback()` and then trying to treat that as a reference.

You can fix this by replacing the line

```
drawBox(start, end, (Mat&) param);
```

with

```
cv::Mat* image  = static_cast<cv::Mat *>(param);
drawBox(start, end, *image);
```

Also, to actually see the box you have drawn you will need to call `imshow()` again. i.e.:

```
rectangle(img, start, end, color, 1, 8, 0);
imshow("Feed", img);
```